# UWP XAML x:Bind not displaying data

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

For my first C# project, I am building a Universal Windows Platform weather application that retrieves data from the [Yahoo! weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/). That part of the app is working fine. The part I am currently stuck on is using `x:Bind` to bind the data to the user interface.

Unfortunately I have no idea what I am doing wrong since an error message is not returned in Visual Studio. I would greatly appreciate your help :)

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WeatherPanel
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public Weather Weather { get; set; }
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        private async void GetData()
        {
            // Get latitude, longitude, and other IP-related data.
            IP ip = await Task.Run(() => GetIP());

            // Get current weather and forecast.
            string weather_url = BuildWeatherUrl("forecast", ip.lat, ip.lon);
            this.Weather = await Task.Run(() => GetWeather(weather_url));

            // This works, so we know we're getting weather data.
            // Debug.WriteLine("--- Distance = " + this.Weather.query.results.channel.units.distance);
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            // Initializes the GUI: sets up buttons, labels, event handlers, etc.
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Weather = new Weather();

            // Get location and weather. Meanwhile, execution continues so UI thread isn't blocked.
            GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="WeatherPanel.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WeatherPanel"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!-- ... -->
        <Grid Name="gd_forecast" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- ... -->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- ... -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- This is not working: -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind Weather.query.results.channel.units.distance}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

weather.cs (GetWeather() deserialzes the JSON response to an instance of Weather)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherPanel
{
    public class Units
    {
        public string distance { get; set; }
        public string pressure { get; set; }
        public string speed { get; set; }
        public string temperature { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public string chill { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public string speed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Atmosphere
    {
        public string humidity { get; set; }
        public string pressure { get; set; }
        public string rising { get; set; }
        public string visibility { get; set; }
    }

    public class Astronomy
    {
        public string sunrise { get; set; }
        public string sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string width { get; set; }
        public string height { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Condition
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string temp { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Forecast
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string day { get; set; }
        public string high { get; set; }
        public string low { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Guid
    {
        public string isPermaLink { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string lat { get; set; }
        public string @long { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string pubDate { get; set; }
        public Condition condition { get; set; }
        public List<Forecast> forecast { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Guid guid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel
    {
        public Units units { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string lastBuildDate { get; set; }
        public string ttl { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Atmosphere atmosphere { get; set; }
        public Astronomy astronomy { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public Channel channel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public string lang { get; set; }
        public Results results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public Query query { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the quick answer just to get you going. You need to notify the view(mainpage) that the initial data have changed.
Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the MainPage then raise the event everytime the value changes.

```
namespace WeatherPanel
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Weather Weather { get; set; }
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        private async void GetData()
        {
        // Get latitude, longitude, and other IP-related data.
        IP ip = await Task.Run(() => GetIP());

        // Get current weather and forecast.
        string weather_url = BuildWeatherUrl("forecast", ip.lat, ip.lon);
        this.Weather = await Task.Run(() => GetWeather(weather_url));

        // This works, so we know we're getting weather data.
        // Debug.WriteLine("--- Distance = " + this.Weather.query.results.channel.units.distance);
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
        // Initializes the GUI: sets up buttons, labels, event handlers, etc.
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Weather = new Weather();

        // Get location and weather. Meanwhile, execution continues so UI thread isn't blocked.
        GetData();
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Weather)); //Raise the event
        }
        //the event to raise on changes
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then set the binding mode to **OneWay** like so:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind  Weather.query.results.channel.units.distance, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I will however recommend you to run your asynchronous calls to the API inside the [OnNavigatedTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(vs.95).aspx) method instead of the constructor. 
Try to use the [MVVM pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) to bind the view to a ViewModel and put your logic there instead of the codebehind.

Comment: I would rather advise you to not make the API calls in the onnavigated to either. It should be inside the loaded event. As putting it in onNavigated to may lead to delayed navigation and UI rendering

Comment: Until the need to retrieve navigation parameters for your API calls which is only possible in the OnNavigatedTo method.